# Calcular el promedio de cada operacion 00:00:00

Tags: powerbi, dax

Como puedo sacar el codigo DAX el promedio de "cada una" de la "DESC_OPERACION" considerando "HOR_INI_OPERAC" , "HOR_FIN_OPERAC" , "DURACION_OPERAC"

Asi mismo esta informacion se encuentra dentro de un tabla de datos en PowerBi llamado OPERADOS_23 la cual tiene las siguientes columnas.

Nota, no sacar el promedio total de todo, si no de cada operacion que se repita.

- HOR_INI_OPERAC = Hora que inicia la operacion
- HOR_FIN_OPERAC = Horaque termina la operacion
- DURACION_OPERAC = Duracion total de la operacio

[image: HOR_INI_OPERAC / HOR_FIN_OPERAC]

[image: DURACION_OPERAC]

*** nota: agrege una nueva columna para sacar

```
TOTAL SEGUNDOS = DATEDIFF('OPERADOS_23'[HOR_INI_OPERAC], 'OPERADOS_23'[HOR_FIN_OPERAC],SECON`D)
```

*** intente con el codigo siguiente

```
Duracion = 
VAR Tiempo = AVERAGE('OPERADOS_23'[TOTAL SEGUNDOS])
VAR Horas = INT(Tiempo /3600)
VAR Minutos = INT((Tiempo - (Horas * 3600)) / 60)
VAR Segundo = MOD(Tiempo, 60)
RETURN
VALUE (Horas & Minutos & Segundo)
```

Pero todas las operacion me sale con una mismo promedio

[image: Duracion]